Cefsharp synchronous call from javascript to c#
In C#, I am using CefSharp's ChromiumWebBrowser to load a URL for a file named index.html. This file contains JavaScript files, including Monaco scripts. I want to call a C# function from within a JavaScript function, but I'm having trouble doing so and I don't know why. My code looks something like this:
cefsharp code:
private ChromiumWebBrowser _mView;
_jManager = new GMManager();
///...
_mView.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("javaManager", _jManager);

///...

public class GMManager
{
    public GMManager()
    {
    }
    public void OnText(string currentText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do things: " + newText);
    }

}


code javascript:
function reportChanged() {
    let currValue = editor.getValue();
    window.javaManager.OnText(currValue);
}

before i was using webview2 i had in javascript "window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync.javaManager.OnText(currValue);" but i had to change to cefsharp and now i dont know why dont work anymore
i tried to put async in the function of c# but dont work.

You've registered the object, it's not bound in the browser by default, you can set _mView.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true; before you register.
